# Predicate Logic and nested quantifiers (translations)

Tags: quantifiers, predicate-logic

"There are exactly two people that Eun likes"

Let $Q(x,y):$ $x$ likes $y$

My solution to this is:

$$\forall x (\lnot Q(Eun,x)\land\exists y,z((x\neq y\neq z) \rightarrow Q(Eun,y)\land Q(Eun,z)))$$

My thought was if Eun likes exactly two people, it means that he doesn't like everybody else. My problem with this is that you usually don't see an existential quantifier with a conditional...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:
$$\exists x\exists y(\lnot(x=y)\land Q(E,x)\land Q(E,y)\land \forall t(Q(E,t)\longrightarrow ((t=x)\lor (t=y)))).$$

Some parentheses have been left out, since though technically needed, they would interfere with readability.

The first part says there are two different people that $E$ likes. The part that begins with $\forall t$ says $E$ likes nobody else.

Comment: Ok, I see how this can make sense.. It seems similar yet different from mine. I'm curious on how "correct" is my approach compared to yours..

Comment: Your version is quite far from being correct. It is consistent with there being only one person in the universe. And there are other problems. It really does not say what the English-language version said.