# Can we express "exactly X" with set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, data-analysis

I have a question that I think that is a better fit here than a programming SE as SQL is founded on set theory and my question is more about set theory than about a programming question.
Assuming I have the following question: "Retrieve all the students who take exactly 2 courses" which should be formed as a SQL query, the solutions I have seen, essentially re-phrase the question as follows: "Retrieve all the students who take at least 2 courses *and do not take a third course*" or  "Retrieve all the students who take at least 2 courses *and do not take at least 3 courses*"
The results of these queries are correct and the formulation of the SQL queries are relatively straightforward (at least when the query is presented it is easily understood).
Now my question is, why does the original query need to be rephrased to be expressed in an SQL dialect?
Is it not possible to express the "exactly 2 courses" within Set theory?

Comment: Of course we can express what you want in set theory. The answers you cite seem to do that. I think a subset $S$ of the courses such that there exists a bijection $S\to\{0,1\}$ would also be a way to express it. What exactly do you dislike about these formulations?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497155/predicate-logic-and-nested-quantifiers-translations

Comment: @marcvanleeuwen:It is not that I dislike something.I am trying to understand why the "exactly" needs to be rephrased to be "captured"

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you meanby "express". There are no students and no courses in set theory (and it takes a while till you have a $2$).

To match your SQL situation, let's assume a set $S$ of students, a set $C$ of courses and a relation $R\subseteq S\times C$.
The students with exactly two course could then be described as
$$ \{\,s\in S\mid\exists a,b\in C\colon sRa\land sRb\land a\ne b\land (\forall c\in C\colon sRc\to c=a\lor c=b)\,\}$$
but also as 
$$ \{\,s\in S\mid|(\{s\}\times C)\cap R|=2\,\}.$$
The first would somewhat correspond to "at least two but not at least three", maybe the second is something you ask for.

Since you can get a list of all students and their course counts from someting like `SELECT student,count(course) FROM studentcourserelation GROUP BY student` I guess that adding some suitable`HAVING` clause should work in SQL

Comment: `I guess that adding some suitableHAVING clause should work in SQL` My question is not about how to form the SQL query.My confusion is mainly about the need to rephrase the term "exactly" to the equivalent "no more and no less than".

Answer (score 1):

The word "exactly" means "no more and no less". Mathematics, and set theory, is wonderful because its "core dictionary" is so small. We define more and more terms, and abbreviate and so on, but when we want to write something formally we have very little to write it with.

So when we want to write that there are exactly two courses, we write that there are two (so at least two), but not three (at most two).

This is exactly what those SQL queries do. And essentially, that is what you do when someone tells you that they want "exactly five oranges": you give them at least five oranges, but not more.

To the question whether or not these queries can be written otherwise, in a more direct way, that is **definitely** not a question for this website.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `The word "exactly" means "no more and no less"` but my question is why do we need to rephrase it in order to    manipulate data sets

Comment: Well then, that seems like a question about the design of SQL more than it is about mathematics.

Comment: But you also explain the term exactly in your answer by rephrasing.

Comment: Huh? I don't see your point.

Comment: I am not trying to make a point.Just to clear my confusion.You note that we "define more and more terms and abbreviate..." so I understand by this that the term "exactly" is an abbreviation of a more general (accurate?) definition. So we turn to the expanded definition to express the "exactly" in set theory?

Comment: Yes. Not just in set theory, though. In pretty much all parts of mathematics.